# How to fix TabView overlapping last List item in landscape mode?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

I am building an iPhone app with SwiftUI and I encounter a layout problem: when I test my app on device or on simulator, in landscape mode the following happens: the bottom bar overlaps the latest List item (marked red on screenshot):

[image: FirstView tab]

My desire is to never allow this, so result must look like this (marked green on screenshot):

[image: SecondView tab]

Details about the app: based on Tabbed App Xcode iOS application template. 3 views: `ContentView.swift`, `FirstView.swift`, `SecondView.swift`. I added dummy List to the `FirstView.swift` to illustrate the problem.

`ContentView.swift` code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var selection = 0

    var body: some View {
        TabView(selection: $selection){
            FirstView()
                .tabItem {
                    VStack {
                        Image("first")
                        Text("First")
                    }
                }
                .tag(0)
            SecondView()
                .tabItem {
                    VStack {
                        Image("second")
                        Text("Second")
                    }
                }
                .tag(1)
        }
    }
}
```

`FirstView.swift` code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct FirstView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List(0..<10) { item in
                Image(systemName: "photo")

                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    Text("Hello")
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("First View Title")
        }

    }
}
```

`SecondView.swift` code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct SecondView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Text("Second View")
            .navigationBarTitle("Second View Title")
        }
    }
}
```

I found the workaround, but this isn't how I want it to work: if I move device to landscape mode, tap SecondView tab, and then tap FirstView tap, and scroll List from top to bottom, tab bar do not overlaps latest List item. Is there a way to fix TabView overlapping last List item in landscape mode? Thank you.

**UPD**: added `func scene()` from `SceneDelegate.swift`:

```
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
    // Use this method to optionally configure and attach the UIWindow `window` to the provided UIWindowScene `scene`.
    // If using a storyboard, the `window` property will automatically be initialized and attached to the scene.
    // This delegate does not imply the connecting scene or session are new (see `application:configurationForConnectingSceneSession` instead).

    // Get the managed object context from the shared persistent container.
    let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext

    // Create the SwiftUI view and set the context as the value for the managedObjectContext environment keyPath.
    // Add `@Environment(\.managedObjectContext)` in the views that will need the context.
    let contentView = ContentView().environment(\.managedObjectContext, context)

    // Use a UIHostingController as window root view controller.
    if let windowScene = scene as? UIWindowScene {
        let window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
        window.rootViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: contentView)
        self.window = window
        window.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }
}
```

Comment: try offsetting y of the FirstView in content view when screen.wdith > (..iphone se phone width)

Comment: @TilakMaddy any way to fix it for all devices? My actual device is 8 sized phone and I see the same problem.

Comment: you can go the scene delegate file and attach an environment object of windowscene to content view , then in your content view you can use `windowScene.interfaceOrientation.isLandscape`

Comment: Also note that if the `windowScene` object is implicitly coerced, then you will have to optionally unwrap it and use it like `windowScene?.interf....` after receiving the windowscene object in content view

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1**:  
In your `ContentView.swift` file you can create a variable inside the struct called

`var isLandscape: Bool = false` 
(Do it above the `var body: ....`)

**Step 2**:

Then go to the `SceneDelegate.swift` file and insert the following

```
 let window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene) <---- after this line insert
                                                       what is shown below

 contentView.isLandscape = windowScene.interfaceOrientation.isLandscape
```

Also make sure you change the `let` declaration of `contentView` to `var` because we are essentially mutating the structure while passing the `isLandscape` property.

**Step 3**:

Now that you have access to landscape boolean in your contentView you can offset the FirstView by a small amount like 20 or something with a ternary check on the property to keep it simple and sweet

like ....

```
              FirstView()
                .offset(x:0 , y: isLandscape ? 20 : 0)
                .tabItem {
                    VStack {
                        Image("first")
                        Text("First")
                    }
                }
                .tag(0)
```

20 is just out go my head. You will have to test by hit and trial to know the most suitable value .

Hope that helps !

Comment your doubts down below :)

**EDIT FOR YOUR SAKE**

```
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
    if let windowScene = scene as? UIWindowScene {
        let window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
        var contentView = ContentView()
        contentView.isLandscape = windowScene.interfaceOrientation.isLandscape
        window.rootViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: contentView.environmentObject(settings))
        self.window = window
        window.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please describe where `contentView ` should be first declared?

Comment: I updated code in question with `SceneDelegate.swift`. I do not see it, when I add `contentView.isLandscape = windowScene.interfaceOrientation.isLandscape` where you suggested I get an error "Use of unresolved identifier 'contentView'".

Comment: what is the first line in the `scene` function ? It should be `let contentView = ContentView()` if you haven't changed it ..

Comment: UPD: now getting "Value of type 'ContentView' has no member 'isLandscape'". I think it should be `contentView.landscape = windowScene.interfaceOrientation.isLandscape`. Right?